ASE calculating Poisson's ratio
I'm new to ASE and as a beginner project I'm trying to calculate Poisson's Ratio.
I have the following code:
import numpy as np
from ase import Atoms
from ase.calculators.emt import EMT
from ase.optimize import BFGS
from ase.constraints import StrainFilter

# Set up the initial configuration and calculator
cu = Atoms('Cu', positions=[(0, 0, 0)], cell=[3.6, 3.6, 3.6], pbc=True)
calc = EMT()
cu.set_calculator(calc)

# Define normal strains to apply
normal_strains = np.linspace(-0.02, 0.02, 10)

# Lists to store strains
axial_strains = []
transverse_strains = []

# Apply normal strain and calculate the resulting transverse strains
for normal_strain in normal_strains:
    strained_cu = cu.copy()
    cell = strained_cu.get_cell()
    original_cell = cell.copy()  
    cell[0, 0] *= (1 + normal_strain)  
    strained_cu.set_cell(cell, scale_atoms=True)
    strained_cu.set_calculator(calc)
    
    # Apply strain filter to relax the system
    sf = StrainFilter(strained_cu, mask=[0, 1, 1,0,0,0])
    opt = BFGS(sf)
    opt.run(fmax=0.01)
    
    # Calculate the resulting strains in the Y and Z directions
    new_cell = strained_cu.get_cell()
    transverse_strain_y = (new_cell[1, 1] - original_cell[1, 1]) / original_cell[1, 1]
    transverse_strain_z = (new_cell[2, 2] - original_cell[2, 2]) / original_cell[2, 2]
    
    axial_strains.append(normal_strain)
    transverse_strains.append((transverse_strain_y + transverse_strain_z) / 2)


# Convert lists to numpy arrays
axial_strains = np.array(axial_strains)
transverse_strains = np.array(transverse_strains)
# Plot the graph
plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
plt.plot(axial_strains, transverse_strains, 'o-', label='Transverse Strain')
plt.xlabel('Axial Strain')
plt.ylabel('Transverse Strain')
plt.title('Transverse Strain vs Axial Strain')
plt.legend()
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
# Calculate Poisson ratio
poisson_ratio = -np.polyfit(axial_strains, transverse_strains, 1)[0]

# Print the results
print(f"Poisson Ratio: {poisson_ratio:.4f}")

However I get a calculated Poisson's ratio of -0.0023 instead of the experimental value of ~0.35. Is there something fundamentally wrong with my code, or is this the expected behaviour for these types of tests?
For reference here's the full output print:
      Step     Time          Energy          fmax
BFGS:    0 08:28:47        2.505671        2.216177
BFGS:    1 08:28:47        2.430329        2.489528
BFGS:    2 08:28:47        1.705594        3.823303
BFGS:    3 08:28:47        0.865879        1.474829
BFGS:    4 08:28:47        1.201491        6.040960
BFGS:    5 08:28:47        0.828921        0.558609
BFGS:    6 08:28:47        0.824068        0.203718
/tmp/ipykernel_72/3973347157.py:10: DeprecationWarning: Please use atoms.calc = calc
  cu.set_calculator(calc)
/tmp/ipykernel_72/3973347157.py:26: DeprecationWarning: Please use atoms.calc = calc
  strained_cu.set_calculator(calc)
/tmp/ipykernel_72/3973347157.py:29: FutureWarning: Import StrainFilter from ase.filters
  sf = StrainFilter(strained_cu, mask=[0, 1, 1,0,0,0])
BFGS:    7 08:28:47        0.823370        0.015624
BFGS:    8 08:28:47        0.823366        0.000543
      Step     Time          Energy          fmax
BFGS:    0 08:28:47        2.514062        2.238912
BFGS:    1 08:28:47        2.437168        2.514338
BFGS:    2 08:28:47        1.708106        3.834156
BFGS:    3 08:28:47        0.867924        1.464547
BFGS:    4 08:28:47        1.188146        5.889666
BFGS:    5 08:28:48        0.831405        0.546492
BFGS:    6 08:28:48        0.826752        0.196485
BFGS:    7 08:28:48        0.826104        0.014856
BFGS:    8 08:28:48        0.826100        0.000498
      Step     Time          Energy          fmax
BFGS:    0 08:28:48        2.522164        2.261197
BFGS:    1 08:28:48        2.443734        2.538536
BFGS:    2 08:28:48        1.710487        3.844593
BFGS:    3 08:28:48        0.869901        1.454362
BFGS:    4 08:28:48        1.175738        5.745729
BFGS:    5 08:28:48        0.833820        0.534789
BFGS:    6 08:28:48        0.829355        0.189606
BFGS:    7 08:28:48        0.828753        0.014130
BFGS:    8 08:28:48        0.828750        0.000457
      Step     Time          Energy          fmax
BFGS:    0 08:28:48        2.529983        2.283021
BFGS:    1 08:28:48        2.450037        2.562114
BFGS:    2 08:28:48        1.712746        3.854614
BFGS:    3 08:28:48        0.871811        1.444285
BFGS:    4 08:28:48        1.164202        5.608823
BFGS:    5 08:28:48        0.836166        0.523495
BFGS:    6 08:28:48        0.831880        0.183068
BFGS:    7 08:28:48        0.831319        0.013447
BFGS:    8 08:28:48        0.831317        0.000419
      Step     Time          Energy          fmax
BFGS:    0 08:28:48        2.537527        2.304379
BFGS:    1 08:28:48        2.456084        2.585069
BFGS:    2 08:28:48        1.714887        3.864224
BFGS:    3 08:28:49        0.873658        1.434328
BFGS:    4 08:28:49        1.153478        5.478622
BFGS:    5 08:28:49        0.838445        0.512606
BFGS:    6 08:28:49        0.834328        0.176857
BFGS:    7 08:28:49        0.833806        0.012802
BFGS:    8 08:28:49        0.833803        0.000385
      Step     Time          Energy          fmax
BFGS:    0 08:28:49        2.544802        2.325266
BFGS:    1 08:28:49        2.461885        2.607397
BFGS:    2 08:28:49        1.716918        3.873428
BFGS:    3 08:28:49        0.875442        1.424501
BFGS:    4 08:28:49        1.143507        5.354799
BFGS:    5 08:28:49        0.840657        0.502113
BFGS:    6 08:28:49        0.836701        0.170959
BFGS:    7 08:28:49        0.836214        0.012196
BFGS:    8 08:28:49        0.836212        0.000355
      Step     Time          Energy          fmax
BFGS:    0 08:28:49        2.551816        2.345681
BFGS:    1 08:28:49        2.467446        2.629100
BFGS:    2 08:28:49        1.718843        3.882234
BFGS:    3 08:28:49        0.877166        1.414814
BFGS:    4 08:28:49        1.134234        5.237034
BFGS:    5 08:28:49        0.842805        0.492006
BFGS:    6 08:28:49        0.839001        0.165361
BFGS:    7 08:28:49        0.838546        0.011625
BFGS:    8 08:28:50        0.838544        0.000327
      Step     Time          Energy          fmax
BFGS:    0 08:28:50        2.558576        2.365624
BFGS:    1 08:28:50        2.472777        2.650178
BFGS:    2 08:28:50        1.720669        3.890652
BFGS:    3 08:28:50        0.878832        1.405273
BFGS:    4 08:28:50        1.125608        5.125012
BFGS:    5 08:28:50        0.844889        0.482276
BFGS:    6 08:28:50        0.841230        0.160047
BFGS:    7 08:28:50        0.840804        0.011089
BFGS:    8 08:28:50        0.840802        0.000301
      Step     Time          Energy          fmax
BFGS:    0 08:28:50        2.565088        2.385100
BFGS:    1 08:28:50        2.477886        2.670636
BFGS:    2 08:28:50        1.722398        3.898691
BFGS:    3 08:28:50        0.880443        1.395884
BFGS:    4 08:28:50        1.117580        5.018426
BFGS:    5 08:28:50        0.846912        0.472910
BFGS:    6 08:28:50        0.843389        0.155003
BFGS:    7 08:28:50        0.842990        0.010584
BFGS:    8 08:28:50        0.842988        0.000278
      Step     Time          Energy          fmax
BFGS:    0 08:28:50        2.571361        2.404114
BFGS:    1 08:28:50        2.482778        2.690482
BFGS:    2 08:28:50        1.724037        3.906365
BFGS:    3 08:28:50        0.881999        1.386652
BFGS:    4 08:28:50        1.110104        4.916973
BFGS:    5 08:28:50        0.848874        0.463896
BFGS:    6 08:28:50        0.845480        0.150215
BFGS:    7 08:28:51        0.845105        0.010109
BFGS:    8 08:28:51        0.845104        0.000257

Thanks!

Changed opt.run(fmax=0.01) to opt.run(fmax=0.0001), got poisson ratio of about 0.39
